# jquery .css change background-image

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I'm trying to learn javascript with my book. I wrote my code exactly the same as is written but my code(jquery) that changes background-image doesn't work.
I searched many times and checked if it has any errors, but I can't find why

Here is my Code

```
  <script>
     $(function(){
         var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
             container : "kinetic_stage",
             width:320,
             height:240
         });
         var layer = new Kinetic.Layer({
             name :'root_layer'
         });
         var scrollPos = {x:0,y:0};
         var cutter = new gbox3d.Kinetic.Util.Cutter(layer);
         $('#btn_test').on('click',function(){
             var cut_rect = cutter.getRect(scrollPos);
             $('#text_rgn').text(JSON.stringify(cutter.getRect(scrollPos)));
             var sheet = $('#sprite_window.sheet');
             $('#sprite_window.sheet')
                .css('background-image','url(./res/screenshot.jpg)');
             $('#sprite_window.sheet')
                .css('width',cut_rect.width+'px');
             $('#sprite_window.sheet')
                .css('height',cut_rect.height+'px');
            var posx = 320/2-cut_rect.width/2;
            var posy = 240/2 - cut_rect.height/2;
            $(sheet).css('top',posy+'px');
            $(sheet).css('left',posx+'px');
            $('#sprite_window.sheet').css('background-position','-'+cut_rect.sx+'px-'+cut_rect.sy+'px');
         });

         $('#main_window').on('scroll',function(evt){
             $('#kinetic_stage')
                .css('top',evt.currentTarget.scrollTop+'px');
                $('#kinetic_stage')
                .css('left',evt.currentTarget.scrollLeft+'px');
            scrollPos.y = evt.currentTarget.scrollTop;
            scrollPos.x = evt.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
         });

         stage.add(layer);
     });
 </script>
```

If I click the button, sprite_window should get the image but it shows just the white blank space

Can anyone tell me why??

Comment: Can you also show us the HTML you are using? And also the KineticJS version

Comment: I'm using HTML 5 and KineticJS version is v4.5.2